# Does using Google Colaboratory give Google access to my code?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I was wondering what the privacy and security settings were for Google Colaboratory. I know Google Drive gives Google access to all your files, is it the same for google Colaboratory? Any insight on this would be great.

Comment: Did you try reading the [FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html)?

Comment: It doesn't talk about privacy and security.

Comment: "All Colaboratory notebooks are stored in Google Drive."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sixth question and answer in the FAQ (https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html) says that "All Colaboratory notebooks are stored in Google Drive". So if Google has "access" to all your google drive docs, by extension it also has access to your notebooks.